# Using URL Rewrite to create a server variable for any page

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I need to simulate a variable used by our application that isn't available on developers' workstations. Is it possible to write a rule that creates a server variable, like say HTTP_NEWVAR with a value but doesn't touch the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires an Inbound Rule. Here is what it would look like in Web.Config:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Set HTTP_MYVAR">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <serverVariables>
                <set name="HTTP_MYVAR" value="123456" />
            </serverVariables>
            <action type="None" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

In IIS server, if you want to create a server variable via Url rewrite module, just add it.
Something like this:
[image]

And then add outbound rule to use this variable:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Xudong. I followed these directions but the variable does not get created. Here is the result in web.config:

        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="Set MYVAR" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
                    <match serverVariable="HTTP_MYVAR" pattern="xxx" negate="true" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="ABCDEF" />
                </rule>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>

Comment: I got it figured out, it requires an inbound not an outbound rule.